# How to extract a specified part of a string?

Tags: c, string

for example, I have a string `char str[40]="ABCD(ak47)"`
then I want to get the part inside the blankets "ak47" from the string

What should I do?

Here's my code and it doesn't work:(

```
        char *result = strstr(str, ")");
        int endpos = str - result;
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 5; i < endpos; i++) 
        {
            copy[x] = str[i];
            x++;
        }
```

By the way, I realise sometimes people use `char  *str` instead. In case of using char ptr, How can we get `str[i]`?

Comment: What do you mean _abstract_? Extract?

Comment: Try changing : `int endpos = str - result;` to `int endpos = result - str;`

Comment: You have to start from `(` and end at `)`....in between you have your result...

Comment: Pointers and arrays are often interchangeable, so you can use indexing like `some_pointer[i]` for both pointers and arrays.

Comment: Null terminator.......

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yeah I mean extract. Sorry for bad English

Comment: And for single characters, use `strchr` instead of `strstr`. Be sure to change `")"` to `')'` as well if you use `strchr`.

Comment: If you are going to iterate the string anyway, why not just use code instead of lib calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Try doing `result = strchr(str,'(');`
2. Now `result` points to `(` in the string `str`
3. Copy characters from `result+1` until you get `)` or `\0`
4. If the read character is `)` nul terminate the string.

Comment: I added `\0` after the last character and the correct part is copied now, however when I print the `copy`, it print out as `ak47?` instead of `ak47`, anyway to fix it?

Comment: lol the question mark is printed because I use `printf("%s \n",copy)`. split it to `printf("%s",copy);` and `printf("\n");` will make the question mark disappear.

Comment: @hoho97 Hope I have answered your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my implementation.

```
#define STR_MAX 20
char str[]="ABCD(ak47)";
char copy[STR_MAX+1];
char *result = strchr(str, '(');
result++;
char *ptr;
for (ptr=copy; (*result != '\0') && (*result != ')');)
    *ptr++ = *result++;

*ptr = '\0';
printf("%s\n", copy);
```

In this implementation,i haven't modified the original string. I guess you may need it for further processing.

Comment: You could make the loop iterator a char pointer too for stylistic reasons, even though I doubt it affects performance. One bug though: you never copy a null terminator into the destination. Please fix the bug and I'll up vote.

Comment: added a statement to add null character at the end of the character array.